# How do I allocate an integer with hundreds of digits in c++?

Tags: c++, long-integer, multiplication, modulo

"unsigned long int" keeps becoming 0.  It has to be a really big integer that I can operate multiplication and modulo on.
Example: 1234^123 % 1234

Comment: You need a big integer library as Jonny Henly said. Nevertheless, 1234^123%1234 acutally is 0.

Comment: ^ is an xor operation in c++, not exponentiation,

Comment: And watch precedence: `1234^123 % 1234` means this `1234 ^ (123 % 1234)`

Comment: pow(a, b) % c can be computed using 32-bit math as long as a & c are less then 2^16.

Comment: @chrizke  No, it's not 0, it's 1193. It's 0 if the op means ^ to be exponentiation

Comment: @doug 1234 xor 123 does not generate a big integer. So – due to context and in my opinion – ^ is the exponential operator in the provided example.

Comment: @chrizke It's also not zero even if ^ is overloaded to do exponentiation since you can't overload precedence. However, I agree with you about the probable intent and that would, of course, yield 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using gcc you can try __uint128_t or maybe use double instead unless you need to do bitwise operations

Answer (score -2):

Two roads you got
1. Implement what you need by learning how to do large calculations using integer arrays with maths tricks for speed up  OR
2. Use a library

I would suggest to go with 2nd option if you are not tied to use external library. One such bigNum library is [ttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/samples)

OR
If you have a option to switch to java, then java has builtin BigInteger, BigDecimal and more functionalities supported. Look at [BigInteger javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: This answer could be improved with some examples.